# How to implement EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARGUMENT macro in MSVC?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

The following code works as expected in GCC, but not in MSVC.

```
#define _EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG_(first, ...) __VA_ARGS__
#define EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG(...) _EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG_(__VA_ARGS__)
```

example:

```
EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG(a, b, c, d, e)
```

will evaluate in GCC(also checked in CLANG)

```
b, c, d, e
```

But when I using MSVC with this example, the result is empty.

And when I checked `first` arguments in `_EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG_`, I found that the arguments `a, b, c, d, e` were all bind to `first` parameter and left `...` with nothing.

Is this because of MSVC preprocessor lacking of [Argument Prescan](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan) feature or MSVC violating some c++ standards?

And how can I implement this *EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG* functionality when using MSVC?

Comment: Which version of Visual C++?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm 2015 and 2017 both tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this because of MSVC preprocessor lacking of Argument Prescan feature or MSVC violating some c++ standards?

Here's how it works as best as I've been able to piece it together in Microsoft.

**1. Macro definitions:**

```
#define _EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG_(first, ...) __VA_ARGS__
#define EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG(...) _EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG_(__VA_ARGS__)
```

...cause the macros to be defined, obviously.

**2. Invocation**

```
EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG(a, b, c, d, e)
```

MS's preprocessor recognizes a function-like macro `EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG` is defined, so off to expansion:

**2a. Argument identification**

The macro's defined with formal parameter `...`; it's invoked with arguments `a, b, c, d, e`.  This is a variadic with no named parameters, so all arguments bind to the variadic parameter.

**2b. Argument substitution**

`__VA_ARGS__` is mentioned in the replacement list for `EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG`.  It's not being stringified or participating in a paste.  This makes it eligible for argument substitution.  Before replacing the parameters, the expression:

```
a, b, c, d, e
```

...is evaluated by the preprocessor.  Nothing is special about these (no function-like macro invocations are done; and none of the arguments are object-like macros), so the evaluation is the same; that is, the *evaluated* arguments are:

```
a, b, c, d, e
```

By rules of argument substitution, that replaces the parameter "name" in the replacement list.  Once that occurs, we have this:

```
_EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG_(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Up to this point, all other major preprocessors do the same thing.  But MS's preprocessor expresses a peculiar behavior when expanding `__VA_ARGS__`; specifically, the peculiarity is that the entire replacement is only *one token*.  You might see commas in that expansion; so do I; but to MS specifically it's still just one token.

**2[between b and c]. Stringification and paste, in no particular order**

This is just a semantic placeholder in this account.  Here's where these operations would occur, but since we're doing neither nothing happens in this case.

**2c. Rescan and further replacement**

At this step, the resulting replacement list itself:

```
_EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG_(a, b, c, d, e)
```

...is rescanned for further macros.  During this rescan, the preprocessor notices that the object-like macro `_EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG_` is being called with "the argument" `a, b, c, d, e` (to other major preprocessors, this is five arguments).

**2c.a. Argument identification**

`_EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG_` has one named parameter `first`, and a variadic.  **NOTE:** Technically this must be called with at least 2 arguments in pre-C++20 preprocessors; many major preprocessors (MS's included) accept one fewer.

For MS's preprocessor, this is called with one argument: `a, b, c, d, e`, which is associated with the parameter `first`.  The variadic argument `...` is empty.

For most other major preprocessors, this is called with five arguments.  `first` is associated with `a`; `...` with `b, c, d, e`.

**2c.b. Argument substitution**

For MS's preprocessor, there is no mention of `first` in the replacement list, so nothing about the associated argument is done.  `__VA_ARGS__` (which is not being stringified/pasted) doesn't qualify for MS's comma elision feature, so the empty variadic argument results in `__VA_ARGS__` being replaced with a placemarker.

For most other major preprocessors, there's still no mention of `first` in the replacement list, so nothing happens to `a`.  `__VA_ARGS__` (not being stringified/pasted) is mentioned, so `b, c, d, e` is evaluated, resulting in `b, c, d, e`; that result replaces `__VA_ARGS__`.

**2c.c. Rescan and further replacement**

For MS's preprocessor, nothing interesting is here.  Since it's done, the placemarker is removed.

For the other preprocessors, `b, c, d, e` is rescanned again resulting in the same.

> And how can I implement this EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG functionality when using MSVC?

In this case you can separate the parameter list from the macro using a helper:

```
#define _EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG_(first, ...) __VA_ARGS__
#define CALL(A,B) A B
#define EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG(...) CALL(_EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG_,(__VA_ARGS__))

EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Roughly, `EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG` expands to `CALL(_EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG_,(a, b, c, d, e))` in an a.s. stage with this approach.  During rescan that invokes `CALL`, which during a.s. expands to `_EXCLUDE_FIRST_ARG_`, and `(a, b, c, d, e)`, after *each* is fully evaluated.  Then during `CALL`'s rescan, the parameter list looks like multiple tokens again.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.